# Chrome OS VM Image

Tags: vmware, google-chrome-os

I'm looking for a VM image of Chrome OS that uses google's servers to auto-update. I've found a [chromium VM image](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/), but I'm looking for google's version, not the vanilla open source one.

Comment: So you are looking for a pirated version?

Comment: @paradroid hmm, I hadn't thought through it that far.

Comment: @antony.trupe You should be able to download a recovery image manually, but it will only boot correctly through coreboot. An alternative would be to download one from google update servers. The best option is still to dump a chromebook/chromebox emmc storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such version (as far as I know).